# Как нарисовать круг в OpenGL с помощью масок?

Tags: c++, opengl, polygon

Мне необходимо нарисовать нарисовать круг с помощью масок, как это сделать ?
Выполнено должно быть в таком виде

```
GLubyte halftone[] = { 0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x55,0x55,0x55, // вторая маска
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x55,
0x30,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x55,0x30,
0xAA,0x30,0xAA,0xAA,0x55,0x11,0x30,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0x30,0xAA,0x55,0x30,0x55,0x55,
0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x55,0x55

};

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

//Рисуем один нешаблонированный прямоугольник

//и два шаблоннированных

glRectf(25.0, 25.0, 125.0, 125.0); // рисует четырехугольник по координатам

glEnable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);

glPolygonStipple(fly);

glRectf(250.0, 50.0, 450.0, 250.0);

glPolygonStipple(halftone);

glRectf(500.0, 100.0, 900.0, 500.0);

glDisable(GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE);

glFlush();
```